# Stock historical data with Investpy

Tags: python, finance, stock

I'm new to python and I want to get the historical data of some stocks. I'm trying to use investpy, but it seems that it can only get one stock at a time.

Is this correct?
If so, how can I merge those single data into one dataframe?

I tried to run something like this, but got only one column (and without the company's name). yfinance doesn't work in my case.

```
import investpy as inv

stocks = ["WEGE3", "JHSF3"]
dfs = list()

for stock in stocks:
    df = inv.get_stock_historical_data(stock=stock, country="Brazil", from_date="01/01/2020", to_date="01/01/2021")["Close"]
    
    dfs.append(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import investpy as inv
import pandas as pd

stocks = ["WEGE3", "JHSF3"]
dfs = pd.DataFrame()

for stock in stocks:
    df = inv.get_stock_historical_data(stock=stock, country="Brazil", from_date="01/01/2020", to_date="01/01/2021")["Close"]    
    dfs = dfs.append(df)
dfs = dfs.T
dfs.columns = stocks
dfs.head()
```